# Why can't I suggest edits from android app?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, android-app

Just downloaded and started using the SE app for Android. It's pretty good, though I still prefer typing on a keyboard.

But one thing I discovered was that even if I'm logged into my account, and can ask questions and vote, somehow when I suggest an edit I get a little red drop down on the top of the screen that says

> This account is not allowed to suggest edits.

**Why is that?**
It can't be because I have <2000 rep, because at that point it's not called suggesting edits anymore......what's going on?

(Google Play tells me I have the most up-to-date version of the app; I am using Jelly Bean, 4.2.2)

<sub>written on my android tablet, using the app</sub>

## Edit:

This question is a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208471/266359), [twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227030/266359). Suggesting duplicates/related questions is not something the app does, either......

Comment: To be noted, you should be able to flag as a duplicate, or vote to close as a duplicate from the app.

Comment: @StevenV Thanks for the info.....haven't yet run into anything on the app that deserves flagging, but we'll see....I should have >2000 rep on the site that I do the most editing on soon (currently ~1500), so suggesting edits doesn't bother me all that much